# Scrolling slow on mobile/ios when using overflow:Scroll

Tags: ios, css, mobile, overflow

To setup an off-canvas menu I have to set the body to "overflow:hidden" to remove scrolling from the body and add it back in to a container around the content with "overflow-y:scroll". When I do this it seems to slow the scrolling on mobile specifically iOS devices.

Is there some sort of performance issue with moving the scrollbar from the body?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Rather than a performance issue this is likely that your not seeing 'Momentum' scrolling on your iOS device

This can be solved by adding '-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch' to your scrolling element i.e:

```
.scrolling-content {
   overflow-y: scroll;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   height:100%; /*A value other than height:auto needs to be set*/
}
```

By default iOS devices use 'momentum' scrolling on the body but adding 'overflow-y:scroll' to an element does Not set a element to 'momentum' scrolling by default

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling for more info

Note: there's a number of Gotcha/Bugs with using -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch on certain browsers

Comment: `//A value...` is not valid CSS comment in this case, I used /* */. See (https://www.xanthir.com/b4U10).

Comment: Thank you for this. I will use this for now, but is there another solution to this problem? The MDN doc says it's non-standard and shouldn't be used in production sites.

Comment: @AvrilAlejandro: its not properly working in the iphone7 sir 1st time scroll is not working and whole screen is freeze sir.do you have any idea sir what's the problem behind that?

Comment: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` is not a standard property, probably removed compatibility :| @Kapilsoni

Comment: Ok sir after removed what i do for fix the scrolling in iphone7?