# Scrolling Slow on mobile version of site

Tags: javascript, html, css

Scrolling is slow on mobile version of my site, robertcable.me

I've researched this issue with no avail. I've tried solutions like taking the background-size: cover off of my css. As well as using overflow. Appreciate any advice that can be given.

Comment: I think I've found your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33601181/6778799

Comment: Will i need to add a scrolling-element class in my html that encompasses my whole document, like a container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I checked the site on my Nexus 6P it was smooth. So I can't recommend anything specific, but here are some things to look for:

1) Any JavaScript running on an scroll event has a serious potential to slow your site down

2) Certain CSS properties can cause some slowdown (box-shadow can be a serious offender)

Looking at Chrome dev tools shows your scrolling to be quite performant. I also don't see any JavaScript running in the scroll event.

Comment: Thats interesting, because it is slow on iOS devices.

Comment: I tested it on iPhone and I am seeing a lack of momentum scroll. If you remove the overflow-x and the overflow-y styles from your html and body tag, you will get momentum scrolling back. I would not recommend those styles on the html and body tag anyway.

Comment: Thank that worked!