# How to scroll the page smoothly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I need to scroll the page on load to a certain position on the page in an animated manner.  And it works fine (using jQuery's animate):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#today').offset().top - 50
    }, 800, "linear");
});
```

However, one thing that it is not is smooth.  Particularly on a mobile device it feels very jerky.

I've seen some CSS animations (using `transition` and `transform`) that are very smooth but can't figure out how to apply it to page scrolling.  Is it possible to do what I want using CSS?

Comment: Sure. Just apply the css-class that contains the css-animation. E.g.: in Jquery> `$(#today).addClass("someCoolAnimation");` in css: well, whatever you want really. [Good starting point here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) . Specifically, you'd want to animate over [translateY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY)

Comment: Added a pure js version

Comment: I notice you mention that it takes 2 full seconds for the scroll to take place.  How much content is being loaded on this page? If you view the network tab of your developer console, what's the number of requests / total size of the requests?

Comment: @cale_b It doesn't take 2 seconds.  That was in response to someone saying to increase the interval to 1800 from 800.  There are very few network requests - they are not a factor.

Comment: @Geert-Jan I've seen these docs.  But I am unable to make it work.  That's why I am asking for a sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the following css:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html {
      scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
    }
</style>
```

You could also try using vanilla JavaScript instead of jQuery:

```
function showIt(el_id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(el_id);
    el.scrollIntoView(true, {behavior: "smooth"});
}
showIt('today')
```

Also consider adding an itermediary element in the middle of the page, example:

```
<div id="middle" style="display: none;"></div>

function showIt(el_id) {
    var middle_el = document.getElementById('middle');
    var el = document.getElementById(el_id);
    middle_el.scrollIntoView(true, {behavior: "instant"});  // Go to middle directly and then scroll slowly to #today.
    el.scrollIntoView(true, {behavior: "smooth"});
}
showIt('today')
```

More info on scrollIntoView: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Also you might be interest in: [Scrolling slow on mobile/ios when using overflow:Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601165/scrolling-slow-on-mobile-ios-when-using-overflowscroll) if you are on iOS

Comment: That doesn't work for me because then the user ends up waiting 2 full seconds before being to do something on the page.  Plus, it's still not on a mobile device.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601165/scrolling-slow-on-mobile-ios-when-using-overflowscroll

Comment: I tried it and it is definitely significantly smoother, however, it's still kind of janky if you have to scroll quite a distance down.  I was hoping for a CSS only solution since it's relying on a GPU rather than the CPU.

Comment: Just a suggestion, seems it seems to be quite tricky with css only. Why don't you have an itermediary point, in the middle of the page say ``#middle`` of the page and do the same but with ``behaviour: "instant"``  to that point and afterwards do smooth to ``#today`` ?

Comment: Make scrollintoviewoptions browser independent with a polyfill and you are secure :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503599/how-to-make-javascript-scrollintoview-smooth/55357885#55357885

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for cross-browser/cross-device decent smooth `scrollTop` I found is using [`velocity.js`](http://velocityjs.org/#scroll). It's faster than jQuery's animate, quite light and supports multiple syntaxes, one of them being the one used by `jQuery.animate()`, so all you need to do is to replace `.animate()` with `.velocity()` (and loading the thing, of course).

I know there might be other solutions out there, but this one has been solid for years, they are always keeping it up to date, I'd say it's a keeper in any serious frontend web developer's tools. You'll find some very fancy names on velocity's [libscore page](http://libscore.com/#$.Velocity). And no, I'm not affiliated. I'm just thankful for being able to use it for free.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `easeOutCubic` or another easing function ([choose one here](http://easings.net/)):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#today').offset().top - 50
    }, 800, "easeOutCubic");
});
```