# How resolve problem with the scrolling site?

Tags: javascript, css

Good day.

There is a page CSS/HTML - http://promocodesoft.com/q/kupon.html

And when I scroll through this site on an iPhone, or on an iPad (only on Safari browser), it scrolls very slowly, unlike other devices. I think the problem lies in JS of something else?

That is, when I scroll through any site and let go of my finger, then by inertia the site scrolls itself for some time. But on Apple devices there is no such inertia. Scrolling stopped immediately when I removed my finger.

What could be the problem?

see video how it works - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fqkr-qKzfl8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about it, because i am not programmer, so i explain my problem how i can...)

Comment: It's difficult to tell without any code what's the problem, but check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33601181) out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following CSS to the page to make the scrolling smooth in Safari on iOS devices:

```
body {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

The page seems to set the `overflow-scrolling` to `auto`, which makes the scrolling stop immediately after releasing the finger from the screen.